# Normalize or standardize map in ArcGIS for a Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I made a raster using the [Euclidian Distance tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/euclidean-distance.htm). How can I standardize the raster using the fuzzy membership module in arcgis (0 to 255)?

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation for the Fuzzy Membership tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/fuzzy-membership.htm). It fully explains how to use the tool and gives some examples of calling the tool in Python.